# How to test SHTML sites in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, dreamweaver, shtml

I am creating an SHTML website and I am wondering how can you test it in Dreamweaver. Do you simply change the extensions back to HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you test it as HTML in Dreamweaver, you're not going to get the expected results, since neither Dreamweaver nor browsers render SSI.  Dreamweaver does have some provision for [coding it](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/143/tn_14380.html), but you will have to test on a development server.

Comment: I was afraid of that...  The problem I am running into is it looks great in Dreamweaver then when I ftp to the server I am not getting the sam results.  I am kind of a rookie and I did not know if Dreamweaver had some sort of vitual option.  Thanks

Comment: When you're viewing the remote page in the browser (meaning SSI is done on the server), try browsing the HTML DOM with Firebug.  That can help you figure out where the SSI might be going wrong.